# Use WPbakery for own custom field

Tags: custom-field

Does anybody know how to enable WPbakery for my own custom field? Currently it is just a plain `<textarea />`. If I copy and paste the shortcodes generated by WPbakery into this field, everything gets rendered properly in HTML.

But how do I enable the WPbakery-Editor for this custom field?

Comment: 3rd party plugins/themes dev support is offtopic here, you'll need to contact their support routes or ask in their communities